# How can I change the z-index when I call each individual image?

Tags: html, css, position, slideshow

```
<div id="show" class="slideshow">
     <img id="slide-0" src="picture1" alt="0" style='position:relative; z-index:0'/></a>
     <img id="slide-1" src="picture2" alt="1" style='position: absolute; right:20%; z-index:1'/>
</div>
<div class="slideshow-thumbnails">
     <a href="#slide-0"><img src="thumbnail1" alt="0" /></a></li>
     <a href="#slide-1"><img src="thumbnail2" alt="1" /></a></li>
</div>
```

Here's what I want to do: When `thumbnail1` is selected, the z-index of `picture1` becomes 1 and the z-index of `picture2` becomes 0. Then, when `thumbnail2` is pressed, `picture1`'s z-index becomes 0 and `picture2`'s z-index becomes 1. How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: By z-score, you mean z-index, right?

Comment: add jquery or/and javascript tags for your question. it will help you getting answers faster

Comment: Just to point out, you have an unnecessary `</a>` after your first img.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

**CSS**

```css
a#slide-0:active img#slide-0{z-index:1;}
```

**HTML**

```html
<a id="slide-0" href="javascript:;"><img src="thumbnail1" alt="0" /></a>
```

Comment: what does href="javascript:;"> do?

Comment: @MiguelStevens prevents the anchor from changing the location of the page. This is only because you're using CSS only. If you decided to use javascript, it would be a lot easier for you and produce a better outcome.

Comment: Oh ok, that's something like void(0) then? I've come passed that in the past. Thanks!

Comment: @MiguelStevens isn't `void(0)` VB? lol been a LONG time since I've seen that!!

Comment: I've seen it in a lot of websites haha, When i hover over some links that don't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    if(this.attr('href') == '#slide-0')
    {
        $('#slide-0').css('z-index', '1');
        $('#slide-1').css('z-index', '0');
    }
    else(this.attr('href') == '#slide-1')
    {
        $('#slide-0').css('z-index', '0');
        $('#slide-1').css('z-index', '1');
    }
});
```

this would work for you.
this uses jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery, try (upon selecting thumbnail 0)

```
$('#slide-0').css("zIndex", 1);
$('#slide-1').css("zIndex", 0);
```

and vice versa for selecting thumbnail 1.

in a general setting (more Images),

```
$('*[id^="slide-"]').css("zIndex", 0);
$('#'+$(this).attr("href").substr(1)).css("zIndex", 1);
```

when binding the event-handlers, you might even choose code along these lines:

```
$(".thumbnail").each ( function ( idx, e ) {
    $(e).click( function ( eve ) {
        $('.slide').css("zIndex", 0);
        $('#slide-'+idx).css("zIndex", 1);
    });
});
```

the last variation presumes that you issue css classes `slide` and `thumbnail` to the respective html elements (or devise some other selector matching precisely these elements).